# Multiple If Exists with AND and OR

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to run a set of queries only if a few conditions are true. Please see one example below, I want to combine first 2 conditions and if they are true then enter begin block or else if only 3rd condition is true then enter begin block.

```
(If Exists(select top 1 * from table1 where [dateInTable]=@date ) 
and exists (select top 1 * from table2 where [dateInTable]=@date )) 
-- Either above 2 are true collectively
OR
-- Or this should be true Individually
(IF exists(select top 1 * from table3 where [dateInTable]=@date)) 

Begin
-- Logic here
END
```

if i wrap these in parentheses it won't work and if i remove parentheses it might not consider OR condition as an individual condition and will discard if first 2 conditions are not true. that means 3rd condition will only be evaluated if first 2 are true.

Comment: `(IF...) BEGIN` isn't valid syntax was my point. The wrapping of the `IF` is causing the error here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this the logic you want?

```
if ( (exists (select 1 from table1 where [dateInTable] = @date) and
      exists (select 1 from table2 where [dateInTable] = @date)
     ) or
     exists(select 1 from table3 where [dateInTable] = @date)
   ) 
begin
-- Logic here
end;
```

Note that `select top 1 *` in an `exists` is just wasted typing.  The `top` does nothing.  `EXISTS` just checks if a *row* is returned; the contents of the row are irrelevant.  So, I just use `1` because it is easy to type.